# Display tested batch and its predicted label in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am using Keras to create a deep learning model (CNN), how can I display all tested batch images and its predicted label?

Comment: Hello @N.IT. Based on your question it seems you're new to this website. In case you're wondering why no one answers, people at Stack* in general think you're question is lacking. People here don't get paid or anything, but they like to help people. However, we're not here to do other people's homework. If you show that you've tried yourself, people are much more likely to help. You can do this by showing code examples of what you tried or which websites you found, but still failed at your problem. Best of luck!